# AJAX form in Codeigniter responds with error when valid [half working]

Tags: php, ajax, validation, codeigniter

From further developments, I have a AJAX and CI email form that works perfectly with javascript disabled (using Codeigniter code) and when on using AJAX there are a few bugs.

When there are missing boxes and press submit it pops up with the error mmessage-great, but when filled in correctly and on submit it still posts the error even though its right and the email i still receive in my inbox.This is really bugging me as its something in my AJAX code and i think i am missing something in my controller.

Another question:On the AJAX form it is posting personal error/success messages- is there a way of echoing CI $success and echo validation_errors(); in this so they are the same?

The code is what i have so far:

TO see my controller follow this link:  [Codeigniter AJAX email validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395228/codeigniter-ajax-email-validation)

VIEW

```
<h1>Contact</h1>
<div id="contact">
<?php
//This is loaded in the view as it wont be used in the other pages
$this->load->helper('form');

echo form_open('contact/send_email');

//success message if passed validation checks
echo '<div id="success">';
echo $success;
echo '</div>';

 // empty div for error messages (ajax)
echo '<div id="errors">';

// empty div for error messages (php)
if(validation_errors() != ""){
    echo '<h3>Please correct the following errors:</h3>'; 
    echo validation_errors();
}

echo '</div>';

echo form_label('Name: ', 'name');
    $data = array (
        'name' => 'name',
        'id' => 'name',
        'value' => set_value('name')
    );
echo form_input($data);


echo form_label('Email: ', 'email');
    $data = array (
        'name' => 'email',
        'id' => 'email',
        'value' =>set_value('email')
    );
echo form_input($data);


echo form_label('Message: ', 'message');
    $data = array (
        'name' => 'message',
        'id' => 'message',
        'value' =>set_value('message')
    );
echo form_textarea($data);
?>

<br />

<?php
echo form_submit('submit', 'Send');

echo form_close();
?>
```

AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {

        // get the form values
        var form_data = {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            message: $('#message').val()
        };

        // send the form data to the controller
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('contact/send_email'); ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(form_data).serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {

            if(msg.validate)
                    {
                    $('form').prepend('<div id ="success">Success</div>');
                    $('#success').fadeOut(5000);
                    }else
                     $('form').prepend('<div id ="errors">Error</div>');
                     $('#errors').fadeOut(5000);
                }
            });
            // prevents from refreshing the page
            return false;   
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like this line (in your javascript)

```
if(msg.validate)
```

is looking for an object, where your script isn't actually parsing any JSON or returning any JSON.

What I can only assume would be a good idea here (after looking at your controller too) would be to check if the `<div id="errors">` has anything inside it in the response

Then in you javascript you would need to make a few changes

```
success: function(msg) {
            if(msg.validate)
            {
               $('form').prepend('<div id ="success">Success</div>');
               $('#success').fadeOut(5000);
            }
            else
            {
               $('form').prepend('<div id ="errors">Error</div>');
               $('#errors').fadeOut(5000);
            }
});
```

will become

```
success: function(msg) {
            $msg = $(msg);
            // check to see if the div with id="errors" contains a h3 tag
            if($msg.filter('#errors').find('h3').length < 1)
            {
               $('form').prepend('<div id ="success">Success</div>');
               $('#success').fadeOut(5000);
            }
            else
            {
               $('form').prepend('<div id ="errors">Error</div>');
               $('#errors').fadeOut(5000);
            }
});
```

Note: I've written this off the cuff so I haven't actually tested it but it should point you in the right direction.

Edited to use id selectors and not class selectors (habit of mine)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When reading through your code it makes sense however still no luck. When looking through other examples they have "datatype: 'json", i am not sure if this is mandatory for my example or if i need something in the controller? I have tried: echo(json_encode($data)); but no result again. At the moment it just disables the AJAX and goes to the CI script. Do you have any other suggestions to why it could be doing this?- Thanks!

Comment: You are loading a view into the ajax request, so it's datatype is html. I can only suggest you then go through the html with jquery to match the `div id=errors` and see if it contains anything